# How to make a list from a csv in python?

Tags: python, list, csv

first question here.

I'm wondering how I can make a list in python from following csv:

```
a b c d
1 10 100 1000
2 20 200 2000
3 30 300 3000
4 40 400 4000
5 50 500 5000
```

From other questions and answers I found, I tried this:

```
import csv
with open("test.csv") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    my_list = list(reader)
print(my_list)
```

But when I print it, the output is following:

```
[['a;b;c;d'], ['1;10;100;1000'], ['2;20;200;2000'], ['3;30;300;3000'], ['4;40;400;4000'], ['5;50;500;5000']]
```

How can I get this :

```
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['1','10','100','1000'],..........]
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: User pd.read_csv and create a dataframe then assign a list to a column in the dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify delimiter, which is `;` in your case and should specify `newline=''` when file-opening to avoid potential problems. Replace

```
with open("test.csv") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
```

using

```
with open("test.csv", newline='') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=';')
```

For more information read [csv.reader docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the delimiter is ';'. While this wasn't the problem, it also sometimes helps using utf-8 encoding

```
csv.reader(file, delimiter=';', encoding='utf-8')
```

Answer (score 0):

Hy! Kinldy use pandas as pandas is the strongest framework in dealing with csvs. after reading your file into pandas you can access every column and row of the csv and convert them into the list.

```
import pandas as pd

wine_data = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep = ' ')
wine_data
```

**Csv I used:**

```
a b c d
1 10 100 1000
2 20 200 2000
3 30 300 3000
4 40 400 4000
5 50 500 500
```

**Results:**

```
    a   b   c   d
0   1   10  100 1000
1   2   20  200 2000
2   3   30  300 3000
3   4   40  400 4000
4   5   50  500 5000
```

[image]